# Array index out of range while pushing to another UIViewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing

It crashed with message "**Array index out of range**" every I call `pushViewController` to this Controller.

I have found the reason for a long time.

I have checked every Array's length and the index when it is used.

But it is really hard to find out the reason.

So,I'm pasting here and hope that somebody can find out the reason.

```
import UIKit

class Notification: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var NotImg = ["one","one","one","one","one","one"]
var NotName = ["系统通知","系统通知","系统通知","系统通知","系统通知","系统通知"]
var NotDetail = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff"]
@IBOutlet weak var TV: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    TV.delegate = self
    TV.dataSource = self
    self.title = "通知"

    TV.tableFooterView = UIView()

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return NotName.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: NotImg[indexPath.row])
    cell.textLabel?.text = NotName[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = NotDetail[indexPath.row]
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    return cell

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NotDetail") as! NotificationDetail
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    setTabBarVisible(!tabBarIsVisible(), animated: true)
}



func setTabBarVisible(visible:Bool, animated:Bool) {

    //* This cannot be called before viewDidLayoutSubviews(), because the frame is not set before this time

    // bail if the current state matches the desired state
    if (tabBarIsVisible() == visible) { return }

    // get a frame calculation ready
    let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
    let height = frame?.size.height
    let offsetY = (visible ? CGFloat(0): height)

    // zero duration means no animation
    let duration:NSTimeInterval = (animated ? 0.3 : 0.0)

    //  animate the tabBar
    if frame != nil {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(frame!, 0, offsetY!)
            return
        }
    }
}


func tabBarIsVisible() ->Bool {
         return self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y < CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame)
     }
}
```

This is the screenshot of the message when the program do push to this controller.

[image]

Okay. This is the next ViewController（NotDetail） 's code.

```
import UIKit

class NotificationDetail: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var NotDetail: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var NotTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var NotTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var NotImg: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotImg.image = UIImage(named: "focus")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

And this is the code of the ViewController(Message) before jump to this ViewController.

```
import UIKit

class Message: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var UsersNameA = ["大哈","二哈","三哈","四哈","五哈","六哈"]
var UsersMesA = ["啊","啊","啊啊","啊啊","啊啊啊","啊啊啊啊"]
@IBOutlet var MessageTV: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MessageTV.delegate = self
    MessageTV.dataSource = self

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    MessageTV.tableFooterView = UIView()

    let options = PullToRefreshOption()
    options.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1)
    options.indicatorColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    self.MessageTV.addPullToRefresh(options: options, refreshCompletion: { [weak self] in
        // some code

        self!.MessageTV.reloadData()
        self!.MessageTV.stopPullToRefresh()
        })

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Not") as! Notification
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Comment") as! Comment
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Chat") as! ChatRoomViewController
        VC.UserName = UsersNameA[indexPath.row - 2]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return UsersNameA.count + 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "not")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "通知"
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        return cell
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "mes")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "消息"
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "one")
        cell.textLabel?.text = UsersNameA[indexPath.row - 2]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = UsersMesA[indexPath.row - 2]
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        return cell
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}





override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    setTabBarVisible(!tabBarIsVisible(), animated: true)
}


func setTabBarVisible(visible:Bool, animated:Bool) {

    //* This cannot be called before viewDidLayoutSubviews(), because the frame is not set before this time

    // bail if the current state matches the desired state
    if (tabBarIsVisible() == visible) { return }

    // get a frame calculation ready
    let frame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
    let height = frame?.size.height
    let offsetY = (visible ? CGFloat(0) : height)

    // zero duration means no animation
    let duration:NSTimeInterval = (animated ? 0.3 : 0.0)

    //  animate the tabBar
    if frame != nil {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(frame!, 0, offsetY!)
            return
        }
    }
}


func tabBarIsVisible() ->Bool {
    return self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y < CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame)
}
}
```

Comment: Where exactly it is crashing?

Comment: In which line is it crashing? Maybe there is a problem in your NotDetail ViewController (so your next ViewController, not this one)

Comment: It didn't tell me and I update the question with a screenshot.It shows the moment when it crashed

Comment: @derdida That seems impossible. Because there is no any Array in NotDetail viewcontroller

Comment: See that thread list on the left of your screenshot?  It's too narrow to show the entire function names.  The crash happens when you are selecting some row.  Is it for any row you are selecting or the last row of the table or?

Comment: Problem is not with this view controller you get this error on selection of cell? It maybe because of some error in NotDetail ViewController

Comment: So if you set a breakpoint BEFORE you load your next VC, there is no crash?

Comment: @derdida yes,there is no crash unless i do select a row and then jump to this viewcontroller

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yes,it jumped to this ViewController when I did select a row before

Comment: So the problem should be in your next VC. Show some more code, or set Breakpoints in your next VC to check out when the app crashes.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question.Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this problem!!!!

The reason is my poor grammar !!!

This code cause the crash

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Not") as! Notification
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
}
if indexPath.row == 1 {
    let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Comment") as! Comment
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
}
else {
    let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Chat") as! ChatRoomViewController
    VC.UserName = UsersNameA[indexPath.row - 2]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
}
}
```

I used if-else statement wrongly and then cause this problem.

if indexPath == 0  and it would do the first closure and the third closure.

So the crash come.   :(

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: In your case, for better code maintenance use `if () {...} else if () {...} else {...} `

Answer (score 0):

You are calling tableView.deselectRowAtIndex in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Please remove that line and your
code should be okay.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: 
    let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NotDetail") as! NotificationDetail
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated:true)
}
```

Comment: No, it is not the reason. I just did deselection to not to keep the selected state for a long time.